# Storefile from spark on windows to HDFS

Tags: linux, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have installed Hadoop/YARN in a linux VM on my local windows machine. On the same windows machine (not in VM) I have installed Spark. When running spark on windows, I can read files stored in HDFS (in linux VM).

```
val lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://MyIP:9000/Data/sample.txt")
```

While saving a file using to HDFS `saveAsTextFile("hdfs://MyIP:9000/Data/Output")`,  I am getting below error:

> org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
>   user=LocalWindowsUser, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/Data":hadoop:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x.

I guess, it's because Windows and Linux users are different and windows user doesn't have permission to write files in linux.

What is the correct way to store files from windows to HDFS (linux VM) using spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the username that you are using to access HDFS with write mode does not have permissions.

The directory `/Data` has the permissions `rwxr-xr-x`. This translates to mode 755. Your username is `LocalWindowsUser` which has read and execute permissions.

Possible solutions:

Soution 1:
Since this is a local system under your full control, change the permissions to allow everyone access. Execute this command while inside the VM as the user `hadoop`:

`hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /Data`

Solution 2:
Create an environment variable in Windows and set the username:

`set HADOOP_USER_NAME=hadoop`

The username really should be the user `hdfs`. Try that also if necessary.

Comment: WIth the 2nd option, where/how do I specify windows env. variable when writing a file in hadoop.

Comment: Just type the set command in a Command Prompt window - the same one that you are executing spark-submit but of course before. Then modify your system environment variables to make it permanent.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet, that will be a great help.

Comment: I did post a code snippet: `set HADOOP_USER_NAME=hadoop`